# Leaflet: how can I find all geo-json features at a certain position

Tags: leaflet, geojson

For a small project we are using leaflet with geojson features instead of openlayers backed by geoserver.

Now, when I click in the map, I want to see a list of all features in that position.

I use the `onEachFeature` to attach a popup to all visible features (in separate layers), but not entirely unexpected, only the top-item catches this click-event and shows the popup.

I have been looking in the documentation and searching for examples, but I did not find something useable. In the openlayers+geoserver I would use the WFS service to get all features, and then I would display the returned result.

Do I need to switch to geoserver, or is this possible with geojson features (in leaflet) as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply proceed in 2 steps:

1. Attach an extra "click" event listener on your features (or directly on the group if it is an L.GeoJSON or an L.FeatureGroup).
2. In that listener callback, use [Mapbox Leaflet PIP (Point In Polygon) plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-pip) to retrieve all features that contain the latlng position of the click. Note that PIP expects an L.geoJson as 2nd argument.

No need for a geoserver, everything client side.

If you want the found features to open their popup, simply loop through the resulting array and use `layer.openPopup()`. But you will need a hack to allow multiple popups to be opened simultaneously.

```js
groupGeoJson.on("click", function (event) {
    var latlng = event.latlng,
        layersArray = leafletPip.pointInLayer(latlng, groupGeoJson);

    layersArray.forEach(function (layer) {
        layer.openPopup();
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/51/

(the above demo includes the hack from http://bl.ocks.org/mpmckenna8/9395643 to allow multiple open popups)

Comment: Ow thanks, this looks promising and will get me started. I will get back to you once I had a good look at it!